# Can't get directory listing of folder I have permissions to

Tags: permissions, chmod, cd-command

I was having some permission problems and used the following command on directory Media:

```
chmod -R ugo+r Media
```

It didn't help so then I did:

```
chmod -R 775 Media
```

Now I get this error when I try to `cd`:

```
 jeff@nacho:/DataVolume/shares$ cd Media
-bash: cd: Media: Permission denied
```

Even though when I do a directory listing everything looks fine:

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 root share 65536 Oct 15 22:38 Media
drwxrwxr-x 11 root share 65536 Oct 15 23:52 Public
```

Note: I can `cd` to Public with no problem. If I `su` then I can access the directory.

What am I missing?

Extra info:

```
jeff@nacho:/var/www/Admin/webapp/htdocs$ mount |grep -vE '^none'
/dev/md0 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755,size=50M)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
procbususb on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=50M)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=50M)
/var/log on /var/log.hdd type none (rw,bind)
ramlog-tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,size=20M)
/dev/sda4 on /DataVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodelalloc)
/DataVolume/cache on /CacheVolume type none (rw,bind)
/DataVolume/shares on /shares type none (rw,bind)
/DataVolume/shares on /nfs type none (rw,bind)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

Comment: Was the filesystem mounted with fuse?

Comment: You should add more info about the filesystem and how it is mounted.

Comment: ext4 I believe. It's a MyBook Live NAS, straight out of the box. Not mounted with fuse.

Comment: @jeff, but how does your system sees and mounts that file-system? Is it CIFS or NFS? What did you do to mount it? What does `mount |grep -vE '^none'` return?

Comment: nfs. i've updated question with added info

Comment: @Jeff, according to [these specs](http://goo.gl/Q8slW), nfs is only supported for the Public share.

Comment: @forcefsck I only say nfs because /DataVolume/shares is mounted to /nfs. Also, that page is out of date but I'm not positive what information has changed.

Comment: What is the output of `id` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" my problem by adding myself to the group share:

```
su
usermod -aG share jeff
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Though that doesn't help me understand why I couldn't get a directory listing to being with (even after chmod -r 777), but the point is moot now.